# Thread safe List for all CRUD operations

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I had a coding exercise where I have to create the following three services:

- Create: to create new transaction
- Get: to get all the records in last 60 seconds and remove any older records
- Delete: to delete all transactions

So for these service I created the below class for transaction storage. But as per my code reviewer, the below code is not thread safe.

Due to using multiple methods to add and remove stale transactions, there are scenarios where valid transactions could be lost.

Can someone please review the following code and tell me what I can improve here for thread safety and performance?

```
public class TransactionMemory {

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public void newTransaction(Transaction transaction) {

        transactions.add(transaction);
    }

    public List<Transaction> trxsInLast60Seconds() {
        List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = transactions.stream()
                .filter(p -> Instant.parse(p.getTimestamp()).isAfter(DateHelperUtils.getLast60SecondsByNow()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        removeOldTransactions(filteredTransactions);
        return filteredTransactions;
    }

    private void removeOldTransactions(List<Transaction> filteredTransactions){
        transactions.retainAll(filteredTransactions);
    }
    public void deleteTransactions() {
        transactions.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any thread safety issues.  As `transactions` grows performance will degrade since each`add()` or `retainAll()` will (eventually) require copying the underlying array.  Note that any method which modifies `transactions` will have to wait before copying the underlying the array **while** the stream filter is in progress, and the in progress stream filter will not see modification.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS for reponse. So how can i improve the code so that we could see real time modifications/data?

Comment: See @aka-one's answer - synchronizing the methods means only 1 thread can access `transactions` at a time (assuming the threads are sharing the same `TransactionMemory` instance).

Answer (score 2):

[`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) class is thread-safe indeed, but it is too expensive since

> all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by
>   making a fresh copy of the underlying array

Here is a solution using `ArrayList`:

```
public class TransactionMemory {

    private final List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    public synchronized void newTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        transactions.add(transaction);
    }

    public synchronized List<Transaction> trxsInLast60Seconds() {
        List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = transactions.stream()
                .filter(p -> Instant.parse(p.getTimestamp()).isAfter(DateHelperUtils.getLast60SecondsByNow()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        removeOldTransactions(filteredTransactions);
        return filteredTransactions;
    }

    private void removeOldTransactions(List<Transaction> filteredTransactions) {
        transactions.retainAll(filteredTransactions);
    }

    public synchronized void deleteTransactions() {
        transactions.clear();
    }
}
```

Since all mutative operations are synchronized, it is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks @aka-one for your response. But what would when two threads modify the collection at same time 1. by using newTransaction methods 2. by using trxsInLast60Seconds methods ? 
Shall we fetch the real time data ?

Comment: Sorry, I closed my account. Post another question for someone to explain to you why your scenario didnt happen